# Maximum of a graph to find volume

Tags: quadratics, factoring, volume, quadratic-forms

I am confused on a problem I have in algebra two that is below.

A bottom for a box can be made by cutting congruent squares from each of the four corners of a piece of cardboard. Write an expression for the volume of the box that could be made from a $7$ by $10$ piece of cardboard. Using a graphing calculator, find the maximum volume for your box to the nearest hundredth.

So, I believe that the equation would be $(10-2x)(7-2x)(x)$ in factored form and $4x^3-34x^2+70$ in standard form. I do not however own a graphing calculator and cannot find the last part of the problem. I have tried going to desmos, however I cannot find a maximum with that equation. If anyone is able to help that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Was it a type-o not to type x after the 70? Also, have you taken or currently taking calculus?

Comment: I'm not really sure if I am going about this problem correctly but I got that after simplifying the factored form

Comment: Check your product/ your multiplication again? Then check out desmos again.  Don't forget x has to be greater than 0 but less than 3.5 . If isn't something wacky happens with the dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track! Your factored form is indeed correct, but the standard form is just a bit off:  $$\begin{align}(10-2x)(7-2x)(x)&=(4x^2-14x-20x+70)(x)\\&=x(4x^2-34x+70)\\&=4x^3-34x^2+70x\end{align}$$

If you look at the Desmos graph I've made [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9rqhdhtzwi), you can see that the graph of $y=4x^3-34x^2+70x$ has a maximum at the point $(1.35,42.38)$, so your answer would be $42.38\ \text{(units)}^3$.